# Listening for keypress when the browser isn't focused in javascript

Tags: javascript, listener

In an HTML page i'm trying to capture key event (even when the browser isn't focus) to pause/stop a song played in background (in javascript). I tried document.onkeydown but the tab needs to be focused. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not possible from js in your webpage only, perhaps with an extension is possible to catch with browser open, but in another tab. Btw what do you exactly mean by tab not focused

Comment: Is it possible...no. User events occur in specific window (tab) that is focused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> to pause/stop a song played in background

As others have said, listening for keypress isn't possible.  However, there is another way to do what you need.

If you use the Media Session API, all the standard media keys on the system will be relayed to your web application.  Here's an example from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API):

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
```

This works for Bluetooth remotes, and phone lock screens as well.  Browser support is Chrome-only at the moment, but this is definitely a useful up-and-coming API that will likely see more compatibility in the near future.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so.  If it were possible, then web sites would be able to monitor your keystrokes when you are in other applications, which would be a security risk.

Edit: Look at Brad's answer.  That's an impressive feature!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on same domain then you can try this link [jQuery: Fire event in other tab/window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151785/jquery-fire-event-in-other-tab-window)

else as everybody suggested that it isn't possible otherwise all browser tab can conflict will each other. Like many sites can have same button event opened at same time `$('button').click();` so click in one time will also trigger event on another tab which is not good as user point of view.